# Can I nest `#include` in a macro?

Tags: c, macros

I'm building a back end interface that can be expanded by third parties, and I want to make it as easy as possible to add a new back end module.

To do so, I'd like to automate the inclusion of unknown header files by just requiring to add an entry to an X macro:

`store.h`:

```h
#define BACKEND_TBL \
ENTRY(HTABLE, "store_htable.h", htstore, htiter) \
ENTRY(MDB, "store_mdb.h", mdbstore, mdbiter)
/* Add more here */

typedef enum store_type {
#define ENTRY(a, b, c, d) STORE_##a,
BACKEND_TBL
#undef ENTRY
} StoreType;
```

`store.c`:

```c
#include "store.h"

#define ENTRY(a, b, c, d) #include b
BACKEND_TBL
#undef ENTRY
```

I get an error: `# is not followed by a macro parameter`.

I tried to escape the `#` before `#include` since that is a stringizing token, but still won't work.

Is this even possible in C?

Comment: you can use #ifdef and have #include based on condition.

Comment: Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. While you can, say, `#define MYHDR <header.h>` and then `#include MYHDR`, macro substitution is performed *after* lexing preprocessor commands. If you did `#define INCLUDE_FOO #include <foo.h>` (and somehow got that through the preprocessor rather than having it treated as stringizing), then adding `INCLUDE_FOO` would just result in the text `#include <foo.h>` in the post-preprocessor source, which would lead to syntax errors when compiling.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, what you could do is this,
Use a macro to control the definiation block,

```c
#ifdef USE_HTABLE
    #include <htabl.h>
#endif
#ifdef INCLUDE_MDB
    #include <MDB.h>
#endif
```

And when you need just do,

`#define INCLUDE_MDB`

Comment: This still requires knowledge of the 3rd party module in the main code. If a developer wants to add a module they would fork my code, add the module files, and register the module in the macro "table" I suggested. Since they control the main code in their fork, a simple `#include` would suffice. My initial attempt did not keep the main code completely clean, but limited the modification to a single line (one still needs to register the other identifiers in the "table").